# Swift 3.0 and Alomofire 4 post request returns date = "Empty request"

Tags: swift3, alamofire

I am new to Swift 3.0 and below is the post call I am trying to make

```
    let newParams: Parameters = ["p_data": ["sync": sync,"data": data,"cmd" : "getEventList"]]

    Alamofire.request(AppLocalSettings.baseURL, method: .post, parameters: newParams, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).validate().responseJSON { response in

        print(response.request as Any)
        print(response.response as Any)
        print(response.result.value as Any)

    }
```

The status code which I am getting is 200 the response is:

```
Optional({
    data = "Empty Request";
    status = 0;
})
```

The url for this post request is "http://sircleschoolps.myauschools.com.au/webservices_v4". Given below is the screenshot of postman which returns some valid data:

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: noted. thanks for mentioning for future questions. :)